# How to store a list of files from disk into an array in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, file-io

In my site, I need to read all files from a particular directory, store them into a list or some object, and output them to the page so that when the user clicks on them they are downloaded. Meaning, I will display the filename of the file on the page as a hyperlink, and when the user clicks on it they will be prompted to download whatever they clicked on.

I am using ASP.NET MVC with C#. I imagine my model would be something like:

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public string Username {get; set; }
    //public List FileList {get; set; } ??    
}
```

Then in my controller I would actually execute the getting of the files:

```
public ViewResult SomePage(PageViewModel vm)
{
    vm.Username = "AlbatrossCafe";

    //loop or something that iterates over all files in the folder
    //{
    //    vm.SomeList.push(currentFile);
    //}
}
```

Then in my view I would render them out. That part is easy.

I am having **a problem** with figuring out **which object** to store the files in as well as **how to actually read them** from the disk.

Let's just say I need to read all files from a folder on my desktop in location: `C:\Users\Default\Desktop\file_folder`. What object should I use and how can I read files into that object from this folder?

*Things to keep in mind:*

1. I don't need the actual text contents of the files
2. Every file from the folder specified needs to be read

Comment: Please clarify. You stated "the user clicks on them they are downloaded". Then later, "I don't need the contents of the files". So how do you expect the user to download the files if you don't have the contents?

Comment: Sorry, I meant like for example if I read in a .jpg or something, I can display the filename on the page as a hyperlink so that when the user clicks it they will be prompted to download the .jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should look something like this. Because you only need a name and a URL for your display.

```
Public class Resource
{
    Public string URL {get; set;}
    Public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Create a list of these and Bind the Name to your value and the URL to the HREF to your display elements.

**edit**
As far as reading the names from the file your controller should loop through each folder and pull the name and path like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=VS.110).aspx)

Comment: sweet. I actually used `Directory.EnumerateFiles` but its pretty much the same thing. Thanks for the help.